# display: inline-block not working, whack-a-mole game

Tags: html, css, inline, block, display

[image]I have to make a "whack-a-mole" game but I can't align the first two elements correctly with "display: inline-block". Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? They align vertically and I need them to be side-by-side.

```css
.wgs {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 640px;
  height: 482px;
  position: relative;
}

.wgs__mole-head {
  left: 109px;
  width: 376px;
  height: 356px;
  position: absolute;
}

.wgs__mole-hill {
  left: 0px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wgs"> (wgs= whackable game space)
    <div class="wgs__mole-head">
      <img src="mole-head.png" class="wgs-mole-head"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="wgs__mole-hill">
      <img src="mole-hill.png" class="wgs-mole-hill"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wgs">
    <div class="wgs__mole-head">
      <img src="mole-head.png" class="wgs-mole-head"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="wgs__mole-hill">
      <img src="mole-hill.png" class="wgs-mole-hill"></img>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a picture of your wanted behavior?

Comment: of couse not working, you elements is positioning absolutely.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I added a picture of what the code is doing now but I need them to be side-by-side instead of underneath

Comment: What size is your viewport?

Comment: From the picture you have supplied it looks as though the width of the two elements is wider than the viewport size.

Comment: Why are you wrapping every `<img/>` element with `<div>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your HTML:
[image]

You need to put both your mole-head and mole-hill
`img` tags inside only one div element like this:

```
<div class="wgs">
    <img src="mole-head.png" class="wgs-mole-head />
    <img src="mole-hill.png" class="wgs-mole-hill />
</div>
```

That should work!

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
.wgs {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 640;
height: 482;
padding-right: 20rem;
}
.wgs__mole-head {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 109px;
  width: 376px;
  right: 150px;
}
.wgs__dirt-pile {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 262px;
}
```

and used the html like this:

```
    <div class="wgs">
        <img  class="wgs__mole-head" src="mole-head.png" alt="Mole Head">
        <img class="wgs__dirt-pile" src="mole-hill.png" alt="Mole hill">
    </div>   
    <div class="wgs">
      <img  class="wgs__mole-head" src="mole-head.png" alt="Mole Head">
      <img class="wgs__dirt-pile" src="mole-hill.png" alt="Mole hill">
  </div>
```

and the result was:

[image: The Result image of the code...]

I hope this helps....